# Copy the content of an element by its class or id in the browser?

Tags: browser

I'm migrating a ~500-page site to another CMS. The old site uses Textile markup for content in the editor and outputs pure HTML, the new site uses HTML throughout, so it's not possible to copy the articles from the old editor to the new one; copying the old HTML from source code and pasting it into the new editor however works wonderfully. I would like to automatically copy the HTML from the old site (contained in a vic with a unique class) into the clipboard automatically. Is there a bookmarklet or a userscript that could accomplish this goal?

Comment: have a look at [Httrack](www.httrack.com), you can also use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to easily select element and copy them.

Comment: @Lamb httrack seems a bit overkill. How many clicks does Firebug need to go from a page to an element's content in my clipboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after posting the question I've discovered you can do this in a couple of clicks in Chrome: right-click and **Inspect element**, then right-click the element in the DOM tree and **Copy as HTML**. Still, it'd be nice to see something faster, and this method unfortunately picks up the target element's tag.